# PHP - Regular Expression For Custom Phone Number Format

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate phone number with following rule

- Must start with following ISD code +352, +91, +33, +49, +32 (string must start with +)
- ISD code must be followed by numbers only 0-9 (no spaces, symbols or characters)
- Must be minimum 8 characters and maximum 15

I am facing difficulty to construct the correct regular expression, so far I only have `preg_match('/^\+\d+$/', $value)` and this is definitely not working. Any help in here is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @anubhava It failed for following string "+9193a8917282" notice `a` in between? I am expecting number only.

Comment: preg_match('/^\+(?:352|91|33|49|32)\d{8,15}$/', '+9193a8917282')

Comment: Aaah, I think i missed NOT (!) for the match.

Comment: `preg_match('/^\+(?:352|91|33|49|32)\d{8,15}$/', '+9193a8917282')` will return `0` which means a failed match.

Comment: You actually need something like `/^\+(?=\d{8,15}$)(?:352|91|33|49|32)\d+$/`. See linden2015's answer.

Comment: You are right, my conditional statement was wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you explain the difference? and why?

Comment: See linden2015's answer. It is equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Must be minimum 8 characters and maximum 15

I'm assuming this is total count.

Pattern:

`^\+(?=\d{8,15}$)(?:32|33|49|91|352)\d+$`

```
^               // start of line
\+              // a plus
(?=\d{8,15}$)   // look ahead and assert 8 to 15 digits must match
(?:             // grouped alternation (uncaptured)
32|33|49|91|352 // alternations
)               // end of group
\d+             // 1 or more digits
$               // end of line
```

- Flags: g, m
- Steps: 30

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BhqIE9/1)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using the regex

```
^\+(?:(?:91)|(?:49)|(?:3(?:52)|3|2))\d{8,15}
```

Comment: It failed for following string "+9193a8917282" notice `a` in between? I am expecting number only.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression should look like this one:

```
^\+(352|91|33|49|32)(\d{8,15})$
```

This page https://regex101.com/ is very helpful for verify and describing regular expressions.